# Get a range of entries based on a custom date field

Tags: channel-entries, search, date

I have a custom calendar I am building for a client. I wanted to filter the fields before I started displaying so I could avoid conditional statements.

Here is an example channel tag

```
{exp:channel:entries channel="calendar_events_and_entries" search:start_date="&gt;1422748800" search:start_date="&lt;1425081600" orderby="start_date" sort="asc" dynamic="no"}
```

I need to know if the search:start_date is over ridden by the second one.

Thank you for any help you can provide.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way you are currently doing it, yes it would. But you can specify or values https://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/add-ons/channel/channel_entries.html#exact-matching

```
{exp:channel:entries channel="calendar_events_and_entries" search:start_date="&gt;1422748800|&lt;1425081600" orderby="start_date" sort="asc" dynamic="no"}
```